# Apache2: Require directive not working

Tags: security, apache2

I'm a tad confused after reading these docs:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html

I wrote this site definition:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/adminer.conf
Alias /adminer  "/var/www/adminer.php"

<Location "/adminer">
        <RequireAny>
                Require local
                Require ip 192.168
                Require ip 10
        </RequireAny>
</Location>
```

I restart Apache:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

and yet from a WAN situated PC I can still load:

```
https://example.com/adminer
```

I am bamboozled I admit and presume I am misunderstanding something or have misread something in the above mentioned docs. If anyone can point me in the right direction here I would be most appreciative. I would rather have access to `adminer` only from within the LAN and not open it up to attacks from the WAN.

**EDIT:** I do see this in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Can that have a higher priority perhaps than my Location specifier?

Comment: The `RequireAny` in this case can be omitted.  If you have several `Require` directives they are by default `RequireAny`.

Comment: Do you have any other `Require` directives or any old style directives such as `Order`, `Deny`, `Allow`, or `Satisfy`?   Even the ones for the root directory location might be relevant.

Comment: I do see this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`
Can that have a higher priority perhaps than my Location specifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "problem" is with your `Alias` directive.

Whilst the `<Location>` directive would ordinarily override the `<Directory>` directive, since it is processed *later*. When there is an `Alias`, the `<Location>` directive is processed *before* the `Alias` is evaluated, so the `<Directory>` container that relates to the `Alias` *target* ends up being processed *later*. In your case, the relevant `<Directory>` container has a `Require all granted` directive, so access is ultimately granted.

From the [Apache docs for the `Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias):

> Note that you may need to specify additional `<Directory>` sections which cover the *destination* of aliases. Aliasing occurs before `<Directory>` sections are checked, so only the destination of aliases are affected. (Note however `<Location>` sections are run through once before aliases are performed, so they will apply.)

**UPDATE:** You should be able to use a `<Files>` directive, as you suggest in comments, so it's not clear why this would not work for you. For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
<Files adminer.php>
    <RequireAny>
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168
        Require ip 10
    </RequireAny>
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I'm assuming all these directives are ending up in the main server config? In which case, the order they are included could be important. Ideally, you would be creating a `<VirtualHost>` container for this one site, which then makes it easier to override the server config.

Note also, that you shouldn't generally be using `<Location>` directives to control access to local filesystem resources, as they could be easily circumvented. For example, in your case, the user could simply access `/adminer.php` directly. As noted in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location):

> `<Location>` sections operate completely outside the filesystem. This has several consequences. Most importantly, `<Location>` directives should not be used to control access to filesystem locations. Since several different URLs may map to the same filesystem location, such access controls may by circumvented.

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight. It's been many years since I worked at length with Apache. Alas you leave open the question of how to solve my problem. Reason being, I'm tempted to conclude that a `<Files "adminer.php">`  section would work (as that has naught to do with the `Alias`, but alas I ended up trying the `<Location>` directive because the `<Files>` one failed to deliver results as well. It looks like I didn't read the doc well enough on `Alias` but with your very helpful pointer here I have and I can't see an example with `<Files>`  only with `<Directory>`.

Comment: A `<Files>` container _should_ work. Note also that there are security risks with using `<Location>` directives to control access. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That works, though I am still pulling my hair out understanding this nuance. If I put that into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, it works, it blocks access from the WAN. Tick. But if I split it so that the `<Files>` bit is in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/adminer.conf, then it does not work! I mean I'd prefer to keep those configs together, and am mighty bamboozled.